# 3-month-old kitten won't eat cat food

Tags: cats, eating

She and her mother used to hang around a lot in the kitchen, so she picked up begging for human food from her mother; not so much going to their designated eatery to satiate her hunger. We thought she'd imitate her and figure out that pet food is edible, but her mother passed away recently before she can even observe and learn. Now she barely eats dry food unless we season it with broth, even then she just eats a couple pieces. We're planning on giving her away too, but we're afraid that she'll starve herself to death in her new home. How can we accustom her to eating cat food, dry ones in particular?

Comment: Are you feeding her human food as well?